# My Pig Script is creating empty files into HDFS

Tags: text, split, apache-pig, hdfs

I've this statement:

```
--Insert a new column based on filename
Data = LOAD '/user/cloudera/Source_Data' using PigStorage('\t','-tagFile');

Data_Schema = FOREACH Data GENERATE
(chararray)$1 AS Date,
(chararray)$2 AS ID,
(chararray)$3 AS Interval,
(chararray)$4 AS Code,
(chararray)$5 AS S_In,
(chararray)$6 AS S_Out,
(chararray)$7 AS C_In,
(chararray)$8 AS C_Out,
(chararray)$9 AS Traffic;

--Split into different directories
SPLIT Data_Schema INTO Src1 IF (Date == '2016-06-25.txt'),
Src2 IF (Date == '2014-07-31.txt'),
Src3 IF (Date == '2016-01-01.txt');

STORE Src1 INTO '/user/cloudera/Source_DatA/2016-06-25' using PigStorage('\t');
STORE Src2 INTO '/user/cloudera/Source_Data/2014-07-31.txt' using PigStorage('\t');
STORE Src2 INTO '/user/cloudera/Source_Data/2016-01-01' using PigStorage('\t');
```

And there is a example of my orignally source data:

```
10000 1388530800000 39 8.600870350350515 13.86183926855984 1.7218329193014124 3.424444103320796 25.972920214509095
```

But when I execute it runs successfully, however the files in HDFS are without data...

Note that I add a new column based on filename. That's why I've one more column in Foreach Statment...

Comment: None of your split statement is true hence everything is null

Comment: My text files have that name, so my first column (Date) are equal to it filename... I don't know why my Split statement isn't recognize the values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input files named `2016-06-25.txt`, `2014-07-31.txt` and `2016-01-01.txt` then the new added column will be referenced by `$0` and it will contain files names.
You have to do like this :

```
Data_Schema = FOREACH Data GENERATE
(chararray)$0 AS Date,
(chararray)$1 AS ID,
...
```

Or simply specify schema while loading files and keep the rest as it is:

```
Data = LOAD '/user/cloudera/Source_Data' using PigStorage('\t','-tagFile') as (Date:chararray, ID:chararray, ... ;
```

Comment: didn't know about this functionality. Thanks for clarification.